# sublime plugin to convert javascript long text into small ones concatenated

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

I was wondering if there's some sublime plugin that allowed me to convert from

```
var xx = 'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text';
```

into

```
var xx = 
  'long text long text long text long text long text ' +
  'long text long text long text';
```

and also from

```
var xx =
  long text long text long text long text long text 
  long text long text long text
```

to

```
var xx = 
  'long text long text long text long text long text ' +
  'long text long text long text';
```

you get the idea

I searched for a while (http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community) but couldn't find anything like that

Comment: to really answer your question, no, of course there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Who needs a plugin?

Example 1:

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>gqq</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>' +</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Example 2:

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>(underscore)</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>' +</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>(underscore)</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Requires surround plugin. oh, and VIM ;)

Comment: While I can't verify this as accurate, it looks neat - except for your logic.  "Who needs a plugin" is followed by "Requires surround plugin."

Comment: a valid criticism. In my defense, vanilla vim is pretty awful without a lot of commonplace plugins, and pretty much everyone has surround. I just wanted to clarify that it's needed for anyone starting out from scratch.

Comment: I didn't know about the kbd tag, nice details indeed